# How to fix background image with scrollView and textviews with edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

How to fix background image with scrollview when windowSoftInputMode appears.
   I used windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan",but scrollview doesn't work
   completely, please help me. Last fields do not appear when virtual keyboard 
   appears.
   I want that background image should not scroll up with virtual keyboard
   and scrollview should show all the fields inside it while scrolling.

Here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/back">
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/cancel_done_btn"
  android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
  android:textSize="17dp"
  android:paddingTop="10dp"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:paddingBottom="10dp"
  android:paddingLeft="28dp"
  android:paddingRight="28dp"
  android:text="@string/cancel"
  android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_signin"
 />
 <Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/cancel_done_btn"
   android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
   android:textSize="17dp"
   android:text="@string/done"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:paddingLeft="35dp"
   android:paddingRight="35dp"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:id="@+id/btn_done_signin"
  />
 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_below="@+id/btn_cancel_signin">
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="times new roman"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Tuesday,May"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/tv_day_month" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="times new roman"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" 7,2016"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/tv_date" />
  </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/btn_cancel_signin">
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_signin_logo"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sign_in_logo"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
  </LinearLayout>

 <ScrollView
  android:layout_width="350dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/scroller_sign_in"
  android:layout_below="@+id/btn_done_signin"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <TextView

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First Name"
            style="@style/sign_in_text"
            android:id="@+id/label_firstname"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/et_firstname"
            android:hint="Required"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_border"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        >

        <TextView

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Last Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/label_lastname"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            />
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/et_lastname"
            android:hint="Required"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_border"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ll_company"
        >
        <TextView

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Company"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/label_company"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />



        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/et_company"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_border"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        <!--android:background="@drawable/contact_edittext_bg"-->

    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ll_address"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/label_address"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/et_address"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_border"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ll_city"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            android:id="@+id/label_city"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/et_city"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_border"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ll_state"
        >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/et_state"

            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_border"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="State"
            style="@style/sign_in_text"
            android:id="@+id/label_state"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ll_zip_code"
        >

        <TextView

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Zip Code"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/label_zip_code"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/et_zipcode"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_border"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

remove this from xml.

```
android:background="@drawable/back"
```

Write in your java file.

`getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.back);`